# RegEx - Matching Parameter Names of Functions

Tags: regex, function, parameters, match

```
var str:String = "myFunction(strParam:String = \"myFunc()\", objParam:Object = {x:50, y:50}):void";
```

i would like to match the parameter names from the function in the above string:  strParam, objParam.

attempting to match these parameter names as words before colons within parentheses has failed.  problems arise using look arounds / my logic, as there could be an internal set parentheses and object properties with colons as seen in the above string.

any ideas how i can obtain these parameter names using regular expression?

Comment: Do you want to match any generic function declaration? Or just one like the above?

Comment: any.  the above is just an example.

Comment: Then you should look for a parser. Regular expressions can’t do that well.

Comment: ok.  that's what i'll do.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A bit contrived, using rubular.

```
\(.*?([a-zA-Z]+):[a-zA-Z]+
```

See [rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/3zZ50NCfc7)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing internal parentheses strings first.

```
str.replace(/{.*?}/, "");
```

then you can match based on colons. Or if it's not enough try to strip it down further, removing any unnecessary information.